# Echo date december 2015

Tags: php, date, echo

I am using below jQuery:

```
$rezultat = "SELECT sum(vrednost) as vrednost FROM vrednosti WHERE username = '$username' AND cas between '".date("Y-".(date("m")-1)."-01")."' AND '".date("Y-".(date("m")-1)."-31 23:59:59")."' ";
```

This works fine, where previous month is in the same year as current date.

But now I run into trouble, because can't echo december, which is different year (2015) than january (2016).

Is there any elegant solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `strtotime` function to get previous month date, pass that time value to date function as second argument like `date("Y-m-d", strtotime("today -1 month"))`, also to get the last date of any month by changing the date format in date function argument, e.g. to get last date of previous month you can use `date("Y-m-t", strtotime("today -1 month"))`.

So, in your case, try this:

```
$rezultat = "SELECT sum(vrednost) as vrednost FROM vrednosti WHERE username = '$username' AND cas between '". date("Y-m-01", strtotime("today -1 month")) ."' AND '".date("Y-m-t", strtotime("today -1 month")) ."' ";
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but does this query select date from 1.12.2015-31.12.2015 ?

Comment: yes exactly, it will produce criteria like that `'2015-12-01' AND '2015-12-31'`, though you don't need hours in criteria.

Comment: Thank you for solution!  I hope that next month wont be any new problems... :)

Comment: :-) no it will not will not be a problem as long as you want the previous month's first and last date in criteria. I've used `date("Y-m-t", strtotime("today -1 month"))` because not every month comprises 31 days, so `t` is better option to get last day of given month.

Answer (score 0):

```
$rezultat = "SELECT sum(vrednost) as vrednost FROM vrednosti WHERE username = '$username' AND cas between '".date("Y-m-01", mktime(23, 59, 59, date("n")-1, date("j"), date("Y")))."' ";
```